# How to not get indexerror upon making array

Tags: python, string

So, I am not exactly sure what I'm doing wrong with this, but I am learning python right now, and upon doing some more research for my problem, it always came up with import and something else which I have not really learned yet.

```
SIZE = 7
people = []
people[SIZE] = "bob", "john", "amy", "jose", "kai", "joe", "leia"
```

I am not sure if this is needed

> people = []

I seem to get an undeclared error without this statement, and even then when I do, it just prompts me an indexerror

Ideally I would want to make this array a "string array" to hold a list of names
... I've tried the following below

1. adding [the list of names with these braces] (not too sure what that accomplishes)
2. rearranging the SIZE or just removing it overall and leaving it like this

> people[] = "bob", "john", "amy", "jose", "kai", "joe", "leia"

needless to say, im lost, appreciate any help or info..
I am aware of the off-by-one error, but deleting one of the names hasn't done me well either

Comment: `people = ["bob", "john", "amy", "jose", "kai", "joe", "leia"]` is the correct syntax for creating a list of strings.

Comment: @zvone if you don't mind me asking, how would it be any different if I wanted to make another well, array like a parallel array for example to fit a phone number as a string for example

Answer (score 1):

In python a list must be enclosed in square brackets

```
people_list = ["bob", "john", "amy", "jose", "kai", "joe", "leia"]
```

if you want to know how many elements in the people list you use len()

```
len(people_list)
```

if you don't want people to have brackets then it won't be a list any more it will be a string, and strings must be surrounded by ' or "

```
people_string = 'bob john amy jose kai joe leia'
```

you can convert the string to a list by splitting it where you want to separate your words

```
people_list = people_string.split(' ')  #< -- this splits the people string by spaces
```

to access elements from a list you must use their index number, first element is 0 second element is 1 and so on:

```
people_list[0]    #<-- access first element from list
people_list[1]    #<-- access second element from list
```

So in you code you got 2 error:

1- first you are trying to access an element from the people list that does not exist, people list is empty []

2- you are trying to assign a bunch of words to a non existing element

to reassign new element to a list at specific index that index element must exits first

```
my_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

reassign second element in my_list

```
my_list[1] = 'x'
```

will become: ['a', 'x', 'c']

Answer (score 0):

In Python, you don't need to declare the size of something like a list. So when the statement `people[SIZE]` is executed, it gives an index error because there is no index 7 to reference for assignment. In your example, you attempt to set the 8th element of list `people` to some sequence, which fails because `people` is empty and has no 8th element.

To create the list that you're trying to create, you can simply do:

`people = ["bob", "john", "amy", "jose", "kai", "joe", "leia"]`

and then reference them with their indexes, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

python is a dynamically typed language so you don't need to specify the size of the list(array)

```
people=[]
```

this line of code is a normal declaration of list(array) people.
but you don't need to do it (doing will not create any error).

you can just type :

```
people= ["bob", "john", "amy", "jose", "kai", "joe", "leia"]
```

this will create a list of people.

and this code will also do the same:

```
people=[]
people= ["bob", "john", "amy", "jose", "kai", "joe", "leia"]
```